# How to just mock the Controller without mocking the dependencies

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have an HTML file like this

```
 <div class="textoutput">
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
        <div class="textdiv">
         <div ng-repeat="row in contactperson"> 
            <div ng-if="contactperson.name">
                 <input type="text" name="conTitle1" ng-model="contact1.title" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\- ]*$/" ng-maxlength="10" maxlength="10" value="" required>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

I am trying to mock the Controller for testing the HTML without calling the dependencies it has but it's always showing me Controller is not defined

```
   beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, _$rootScope_, $templateCache, $http, _$controller_) {

        $scope = _$rootScope_;
        $controller = _$controller_;
        var directiveTemplate = null;
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onload = function () {
            directiveTemplate = this.responseText;

        };
        var url1 = "TextOutput.html";
        req.open('get', url1, false);
        req.send();

        var controller=$controller{'TestController'{}),


        $templateCache.put('template.html', directiveTemplate);
        templateHtml = $templateCache.get('template.html');
        formElem = angular.element('<div>' + templateHtml + '</div>');
        htmlform = $compile(formElem)($scope);

    }));
```

Comment: If you are using dependencies into your code then, you need to inject them.

Comment: Controller has lot of dependencies..injecting each and every one of them is painful..is there any way around?